# Antlr difference between BaseErrorListener and visitErrorNode in ParseTreeListener

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Kindly let me know the difference between BaseErrorListener and visitErrorNode and when they should be used.

Comment: I'm also confused by this. I'm using a visitor, not a listener, but `visitErrorNode()` is never called when I add some garbage input, even though `parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors()` returns `1`. `addErrorListener` always seems to work however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antlr4 Listeners and Visitors - which to implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714492/antlr4-listeners-and-visitors-which-to-implement)